# gatsby-node isn't building tags pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to implement tags to this website's blog using this tutorial [Creating Tags Pages for Blog Posts](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-tags-and-categories-to-blog-posts/) from gatsbyjs.org. Copied and pasted both /templates/tags.js and /pages/tags.js, only editing gatsby-node.js with parts of the code the guide suggested. I did that because I'm already using a different code for generating blog post pages programmatically. The [whole repo can be found here](https://github.com/edueter/gatsby-theme-cripto).

The thing is there's a page to display all tags gathered by the graphQL, but no pages at all to display posts marked with such. The links in that first one drive you to the default 404 pages. 
I'm not sure what could be wrong.

/templates/tags.js

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
// Components
import { Link, graphql } from "gatsby"
const Tags = ({ pageContext, data }) => {
  const { tag } = pageContext
  const { edges, totalCount } = data.allMarkdownRemark
  const tagHeader = `${totalCount} post${
    totalCount === 1 ? "" : "s"
  } tagged with "${tag}"`
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{tagHeader}</h1>
      <ul>
        {edges.map(({ node }) => {
          const { slug } = node.fields
          const { title } = node.frontmatter
          return (
            <li key={slug}>
              <Link to={slug}>{title}</Link>
            </li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
      {/*
              This links to a page that does not yet exist.
              You'll come back to it!
            */}
      <Link to="/tags">All tags</Link>
    </div>
  )
}
Tags.propTypes = {
  pageContext: PropTypes.shape({
    tag: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }),
  data: PropTypes.shape({
    allMarkdownRemark: PropTypes.shape({
      totalCount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      edges: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.shape({
          node: PropTypes.shape({
            frontmatter: PropTypes.shape({
              title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            }),
            fields: PropTypes.shape({
              slug: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            }),
          }),
        }).isRequired
      ),
    }),
  }),
}
export default Tags
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($tag: String) {
    allMarkdownRemark(
      limit: 2000
      sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
      filter: { frontmatter: { tags: { in: [$tag] } } }
    ) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          fields {
            slug
          }
          frontmatter {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Taking a look at the /templates/tags.js file, there's this chunk of code saying 
*This links to a page that does not yet exist. You'll come back to it!* This leads me to think there's something missing, maybe in another guide or so, but I'm not really managing to find or realize what it is.

gatsby-node.js

```
const path = require(`path`)
const _ = require("lodash")

exports.createPages = async ({ actions, graphql, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const blogPostTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/blogPost.js`)
  const tagTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/tags.js`)


  const result = await graphql(`
    {
      allMarkdownRemark(
        sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] }
        limit: 1000
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            fields {
              slug
            }
            frontmatter {
              tags
            }
          }
        }
      }
      tagsGroup: allMarkdownRemark(limit: 2000) {
        group(field: frontmatter___tags) {
          fieldValue
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  // Handle errors
  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(`Error while running GraphQL query.`)
    return
  }

  // Extract blog data from query
  const blogPage = result.data.allMarkdownRemark

  blogPage.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: `/blog/${_.kebabCase(node.fields.slug)}`,
      component: blogPostTemplate,
      context: {}, // additional data can be passed via context
    })
  })

  // Extract tag data from query
  const tags = result.data.tagsGroup.tagsGroup

  // Make tag pages
  tags.forEach(tag => {
    createPage({
      path: `/tags/${_.kebabCase(tag.fieldValue)}/`,
      component: tagTemplate,
      context: {
        tag: tag.fieldValue,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

I've called allMarkdownRemark.edges.node.frontmatter.tags since it's called in the guide. Not sure where it goes since it's not referenced anywhere within this code, but I believe it's used to build the tag page.

Any comments, tips, requests, and help with this would be much appreciated. 
Thank you for reading!

Comment: Is your query from `gatsby-node` sourcing and getting al tags to create pages?

Comment: It's working as expected, delivering everything with no errors.

Comment: @FerranBuireu thanks for the edits!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `gatsby-node.js` replace:

```js
// Extract tag data from query
const tags = result.data.tagsGroup.tagsGroup
```

with:

```js
const tags = result.data.tagsGroup.group
```

Your Graphql query is querying:

```
tagsGroup: allMarkdownRemark(limit: 2000) {
   group(field: frontmatter___tags) {
      fieldValue
   }
}
```

So your data of interest is at `tagsGroup.group`. With this change your build is working and the pages are generated correctly.
You can test it by navigating to `localhost:8000/tags`.

Comment: It was precisely that, @AWolf. Thanks for point that out. I guess that my head is all tired of this home office routine thing and I not only have typed it wrong, but missed it in every single revision. Thanks for real!